# Bind different events with jQuery eq() and not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("tr").find("td").eq(2).click(function(){
      alert('hi');
  });

  $("tr").find("td").not().eq(2).click(function(){
      alert('hi2');
  });

});
```

What I'm trying to do here is bind a different click event for the every 3rd `<td>` of each row and every other `<td>` different click function. 1st function works but how can I bind event for the `<td>`'s which are not the 3rd ones?

Comment: Try using `on('click')` instead of `click`.

Comment: click function calls on(click). It's not the issue. Please read the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the selector to the `not` method.

```
$("tr").find("td").not(':eq(2)').click(function(){
     alert('hi2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9HUB/

Answer (score 1):

try this out live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yF4QW/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("tr").find("td:eq(2)").click(function(){
        alert('hi2');
      });

      $("tr").find("td:not(:eq(2))").click(function(){
           alert('hi');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("td:not(:eq(2)")`

```
$("tr").find("td:not(:eq(2)").click(function(){
    alert('hi2');
});
```

Comment: write some explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("tr").find("td:eq(2)").click(function(){
      alert('hi');
  });

  $("tr").find("td:lt(2)").click(function(){
      alert('hi2');
  });

});
```